# Optimize for CPU/GPU or system bus bandwidth?

Tags: vulkan

My app has a `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT` buffer and a permanent command buffer that uploads the memory to a `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` buffer.

I have two questions about this setup. This is question 2, question 1 is separate.

---

I have an UBO buffer that is subdivided in 80 byte *rows*. The rows are 1024 for a total of 80KB. This buffer is transfered from host memory to device-local memory at every frame. At 60 Hz, that's 4.69 MB/s.

I understand that a PCIe 1.0 single lane (x1) has a 250 MB/s bandwidth. This means I sap less than 1.9% with my UBO stream. And at x16 lanes or higher PCIe versions (2.0, 3.0, ...) this percentage gets vanishingly low.

I wonder if I should optimize the UBO *row* to reduce bandwidth by employing more CPU/GPU compute resources.

For example, an RGBA color can fit in 32 bits (`uint32_t`) but requires bit shifting and or-ing (and maybe 4 ands with masks to be on the safe side):

```cpp
v = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a;
```

This "packing" and "unpacking" must be done on the CPU and GPU side. The reason to do this is to safe space, because currently the *row* takes a `glm::vec4` (16 bytes) to store color information, which is 4 times as much.

Other values like an angle are stored in a float (4 bytes), but if I need just 256 directions (or even 8 directions) I could pack the angle in a single byte.

By packing translation, rotation, scaling factor and color information in bytes and by bit-fiddling I can go as low as 16 bytes per *row*. This is 1/5 of the current memory footprint and would result in 1/5 of the bandwidth (under 1 MB/s).

Now, this comes at the cost of:

1. a lot of code to write;
2. maybe more brittle and exposed to physical device details(?);
3. less maintainability and readability;
4. more CPU/GPU cycles.

My question is this. As a general rule, for PC and maybe consoles (not smart phones) is this even something to think about? I've read somewhere that on the way from OpenGL to Vulkan they dropped half precision types... as if system bus bandwidth was a bottleneck of the past about which not to care about anymore.

Am I better off just going with Vulkan paradigm (which has a 4-byte footprint even for bools: `VkBool32`) or is this still a valid concern to think about?

Comment: Why are you optimizing if it's not slow? (aka premature optimization). Also, AFAIK, Vulkan still supports half precision types for storage (through `unpackHalf2x16`), what they 'dropped' is half-precision for calculations.

Comment: This is most probably premature optimization. I don't like it when Unity games run GPUs super-hot just to render simple terrain because devs didn't optimize or vsync. What I like is a cool GPU, no fans, no wasted heat, and still perfect performance. To get there, I think that performance cannot be an after-thought but must be considered at every step. Same for draw calls. If you can get EXACTLY THE SAME RESULT with 4 draw calls, why have 1000? Safe dev time? This is all new for me, so I need to think and tinker a lot with all of this stuff :)

Comment: @pid: "*To get there, I think that performance cannot be an after-thought but must be considered at every step.*" Nobody has gotten there by trying to optimize before figuring out what makes the GPU hot.

Comment: @pid: "*If you can get EXACTLY THE SAME RESULT with 4 draw calls, why have 1000?*" Because having 1000 might improve flexibility for the user. Or require less CPU work. Or any number of other reasons. Without knowing the specifics of the circumstances, who is to say that one would be better than the other.